# How to prevent status bar overlap due to "justify-content: center" when keyboard shows?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-flexbox

I center all the content of my screen vertically with `justifyContent: center`.
When I focus an input in that screen and the keyboard shows up, the top content overlaps with the status bar even though I'm using `SafeAreaView`.
How to prevent that overlap? I want the status bar to cover the content.

What I tried:

- Adding top padding to the screen, but it didn't work.
- Removing `justifyContent: center`, and actually the top of my content stopped overlapping with the status bar, but I still want to center the content.

Tried to mimic what I have in my project here: https://snack.expo.io/X0JCnVkwq

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

Comment: I think, it works as expected in your given example. If I remove  `justifyContent: center`, it looks like your image but without any change, I cannot see an error. Do you work or check the rendering on a phone or desktop computer? Have you tried to refresh your cache?

Comment: Did you try code    <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"   in AndroidManifest.xml . Also use "KeyboardAwareScrollView" instead of ScrollView

Comment: @Rene I use an android device. I actually am not sure if the link I privided reproduces the issue. Sorry

Comment: @RAGHVENDERKATARIA I use Expo. I read that KeyboardAwareScrollView not straigtforward and not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by conditionally setting `justifyContent` property. `flex-start` when keyboard is visible. `center` when keyboard is not visible.
Not the best approach, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**KeyboardAvoidingView**

Use react-native KeyboardAvoidingView 
this may help to fix the problem

https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview